# Replacing rows of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, math, linear-algebra

I'm trying to emulate Cramer's rule for indefinite number of variables. This is what I have so far

```
def cramers(n)
    matrix = []
    for i in range(0, n):
        matrix.append([])
        for j in range(0, n+1):
            matrix[i].append(0)
            matrix[i][j] = float(input("V" + str(i+1) + str(j+1) + ": "))
    #n = 2, V11 = 1, V12 = 2, V13 = 3, V21 = 4, V22 = 5, V23 = 6

    mat = np.array(matrix)
    matA = mat[0:n, 0:n]
    matB = mat[0:n, n:]

    matATrans = matA.transpose()
    matBTrans = matB.transpose()
```

for n = 2, these are sample input values of matATrans and matBTrans:

```
matATrans = [[1. 4.], [2. 5.]]
matBTrans = [3. 6.]
```

My question is, how can I produce a numpy array, mat, with n = 2 length for instance, whose value contains this?

```
mat = [[[3. 6.],[2. 5.]],[[1. 4.],[3. 6.]]]
```

Basically, the (n-1)th element of matATrans is replaced by matBTrans. I'm thinking it could be done using a forloop. This was my attempt.

```
for i in range(n):
    matATrans[i] = matBTrans
    print(matATrans)
```

The result is this:

```
[3. 6.],[2. 5.]
[3. 6.],[3. 6.]
```

Obviously, it's wrong because the content of matATrans has been altered in the first loop. Also, it still isn't appended to a mat matrix.

Please enlighten me. Thanks

Comment: What's the purpose of doing this?

Comment: I'm trying to program my own solver for system of linear equations using Cramer's rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, when you assign a list to a new variable you're just creating another reference to the same object, that is the reason for the current behavior. One way to fix this is to use the `copy` method and copy the matrix A each loop.

```py
n = 2
matATrans = [[1, 4], [2, 5]]
matBTrans = [3, 6]

result = []
for i in range(n):
    temp = matATrans.copy()
    temp[i] = matBTrans
    result.append(temp)

print(result)
```